# Are there specific mantras or hymns created by Navagrahas?

Tags: puranas, mantras, stotra, navagraha

I have read about Narasimha Stuti By Shani (Saturn).
Was wondering if there were other stotras mentioned in Puranas created by the rest of 8 grahas.

Answer (score 5):

There is [a Shiva Stuti by Deva Guru Brihaspati](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/stotras/stotra29.html) found in the Skanda Purana:

> Namo Rudraya, Neelaaya, Bhimaya Paramaatmaney,
>  Kapardiney
> Sureshaya, Vyomakeshaya vai Namah/
>  Vrushabhadwajaaya Somaaya
> Somanathaaya Shambhavey,
>  Digambaraaya Bhargaaya Umaakaanthaya vai
> Namah,
>  Tapomayaya Bhavyaya Sivasreshthaaya Vishnavey,
> Vyalapriyaya Vyaalaaya Vyalaanaampathaye Namah /
>  Mahidharaya
> Vyaghraya Pashunam pathaye Namah,
>  Puraanthakaaya Simhaaya
> Shaardulaaya Makhaaya cha /
>  Meenaya Meena nathaaya Siddhaya
> Parameshtiney,
>  Kaamaanthakaya Buddhaaya Buddheenaam pathaye namah
> /
>  Kapothaya Vishishtaaya Sishtaaya Sakalaatmaney,
>  Vedaaya Veda
> Jeevaaya Veda Guhyaya vai Namah /
>  Deerghaya Deergha Rupaya
> Deerghaarthaya vinaashiney,
>  Namo Jagatprathishthaaya Vyomarupaaya
> vai Namah/
>  Gajaasura Mahaakaalay andhakaasura bhediney,
> Neelalohitha Suklaaya Chanda Munda Priyaya cha /
>  Bhakti Priyaya
> Devaaya Jnaaney Jnaanavyaya cha,
>  Maheshaya Namasthubhyam Mahadeva
> Haraaya cha /
>  Trinetraya Tri Vedaya Vedaangaaya Namo Namah,
> Arthaya cha Artha rupaaya Paramaarthaya vai Namah /
>  Viswa Bhushaya
> Viswaya Vishwanaadhaya vai Namah,
>  Shankaraayacha Kaalaaya
> Kaalaavayarupiney /
>  Aruupaaya Viruupaaya Sukshma Sukashmaya vai
> Namah,
>  Smashaana vaasiney Bhuyo Namasthey krutthi vaasasey/
> Shashaanka Shekharayeshaa yograbhumishayaya cha,
>  Durgaya
> Durgapaaraya Durgaavayava sakshiney/
>  Linga Rupaaya Lingaaya
> Lingaanaam pathayenamah,
>  Namah Pralaya Rupaaya Pranavarthaya vai
> Namah/
>  Namo Namaha kaarana kaaranaaya Mrityunjayaaya atmabahva
> swarupiney,
>  Sri Thriyambikaayaasitikantha Sarva Gauripathey Sakala
> Mangala hetavey namah/

I am not giving the translation as it is not required here to do so. To show that it was said by Brihaspati (who is one of the Navagrahas) I'm simply quoting the following passage from the same linked page:

> Whoever is desirous of performing Pradosha Vrata ought to recite the
> Siva Stothra; by so saying Guru Briahaspathi asked to perform the
> Padosha Vrata at once and take on Demon Vritrasura to secure Glorious
> Victory by the Grace of Maha Siva.Deva Guru also explained the
> background of Vritrasura who was cursed by Devi Uma Herself in his
> earlier birth as Chitrarath, a Celestial King. The latter was
> travelling various Dwipas by air and witnessed Siva with Devi Uma on
> His lap and joked that Siva too like human beings could not resist the
> temptation of women. Devi Uma cursed the King at once to give birth
> and assume the form of a Raakshasa and that was the origin of Demon
> Vritrasura.

We can also use the book ["Essence of Skanda Purana"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/skandapurana7.html) as the reference here.

Quoting from there:

> Deva Guru Brihaspathi taught the Procedure of Worship to Bhagavan Siva
> on Kartika month’s Sukla Paksha Pournami or the full moon day; On that
> day, during the noon time one has to perform Puja formally to a Siva
> Linga; if the Puja is done to a Linga in a Village, it would be good,
> but outside village/Township is hundred times better; another hundred
> times better in a forest; and on a mountain top or a Tapovan, it is
> thousand times better!
>
> At Pradosh time, the devotee should observe silence, light up thousand
> or at least thirty two lights with ghee (classified butter), perform
> ‘Shodasopacharas’ with flowers, fruits, incense sticks, sandal paste,
> naivedya (food offering) and so on. Later on, the devotee should
> execute hundred and eight ‘Pradakshinas’ or circumambulations and
> Namaskars followed by ‘Stuti’ or commendation as follows: Siva Stuti:
>
> ‘Namo Rudraya, Neelaaya, Bhimaya Paramaatmaney,
>  Kapardiney
> Sureshaya, Vyomakeshaya vai Namah/
>  Vrushabhadwajaaya Somaaya
> Somanathaaya Shambhavey,
>  Digambaraaya Bhargaaya Umaakaanthaya vai
> Namah,

So, this is one of the Stotras which was composed by a Navagraha deity.